# Proving that any lower bounded set has an infimum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I've reached a point in a larger proof where I determined that a subset of the rational numbers, *$X_n$* is bounded from below. I now need to prove that *$X_n$* has an infimum in $\mathbb R$.

Intuitively this is clear, since the infimum would just be min(*$X_n$*) if *$X_n$* if it is a closed interval or isolated numbers, and would just be "*$a$*" if *$X_n$* was an open interval (*$a$*,*$b$*). However, I am struggling to convert this into an actual proof.

My attempt was to just choose the lower bound L such that $\exists$ L s.t. $\forall$ x $\in$ *$X_n$*, L $\leq$ x  &  if $\exists$ L' s.t L'$\leq$ x $\forall$ x $\in$ *$X_n$*, then L'$\leq$ L, which would make L the infimum, but that seems as though I'm only defining an infimum and not showing that it actually exists.

Comment: @MartinR The answers there assume axiom of completeness which I don't believe is specifically assumed in my class. The class uses ZFC axioms.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in your title is *equivalent* to the axiom of completeness. If you have a definition of the real numbers, for instance as Dedekind cuts of the rationals, then you can prove it.